# Is there a way to determine if a client received an HTTP response in .NET?

Tags: .net, http, httpcontext, httplistener

I'm using an HttpListener and HttpContexts, and I know when writing the response you can determine if it was *sent* properly, but how can you tell if the client *received* it?

I suppose you could set up some kind of message acknowledgement system between the server and client, but I'm wondering if there's something that can do this for me transparently.

A response to a similar question using WCF refers to ReliableSessions, but I'm not sure fitting in WCF into my application would be worth it. I'm not very familiar with WCF, but it seems to me like it's not tailored to the traditional web server request/response model and caters more to disitributed system type stuff (this is more a gut feeling I get from looking through the documentation for reliable sessions, so please correct me if I'm wrong).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"I suppose you could set up some kind of message acknowledgement system between the server and client". I'm afraid you'd *have* to. AFAIK there's not "native" acknowledgement method in HTTP.

Comment: Plus, the fact that the client received the message does not really guarantee that he was able to handle it (before, say, crashing, or power cut, or whatever). So for any critical transaction, you're going to need to implement some ACK messages as the author of this answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

On the server you can call Response.Flush which will send all currently buffered data (and headers) synchronously to the client. After the call finished you know the data was handed over to the TCP stack.

ASP.NET does not provide a way to make sure the TCP buffers are flushed. And even if it did there could be ambiguous cases where the client received the response but the network swallowed the acknowledgement.

This is the Generals Problem and it is unsolvable.

At this point you'd need to provide details on your intent because, as I said, there is no perfect solution.

Comment: That makes sense. My intent is to ensure that messages lost in transit are noticed, and to that end my plan is to have the client send a message (with an ID), and have the server respond. If the client thinks the server didn't get the message, it resends the request. If the server receives a duplicate request, it sends a cached copy of the response. 

I wonder how the WCF ReliableSession over HTTP is implemented, though.